# How to shift Historical Closing price to the left within Array X number of points and fill the gap with price points each equal to last price?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxi4u.png)[image: Blue Line - expected LeftShiftedArray.png]

All I want is to shift Historical Closing price data within Array to the left and fill the gap with points each equal to last price. I am getting Error! message from the history referencing operator. What is strait forward in Excel is so damn complicated in Pine Script. There should be some workaround trick to solve that problem.

```
//@version=5
indicator('ArrayShift', overlay=true)
Shift = input.int(-100,"Shift")

//HistoricalClose Array
a = array.new_float(1)
array.set(a, 0, close)
HistClose = array.get(a, 0) [Shift]
plot(HistClose, 'HistClose', color.new(color.blue, 0), 6)//,offset = Shift)
// Error! Invalid number of bars back [-100] within the history referencing operator. The value must be >=0
// How to overcome history referencing operator left shift limitation and fill the gap with price points each equal to last price?
```

I am expecting getting left shifted array (like it is shown in the picture attached in blue) that can be referenced by a Study like ta.wma() without producing errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the line 'HistClose'. That isn't the proper way to access an array. I would also just use `array.unshift` rather than setting the 0 index every bar, however both will get the desired result.

```
//@version=5
indicator('ArrayShift', overlay=true)
Shift = input.int(-100,"Shift")

//HistoricalClose Array
a = array.new_float()
array.unshift(a, close)
plot(a.get(0), 'HistClose', color.new(color.blue, 0), 4, offset = Shift)
```

[image: close offset]

Comment: Thanks for trying, but plot Offset doesn't solve the problem. The problem is how to Left Shift Data Points within Array without Plot Offset. If I needed to left shift plot, I would do it without using array function with one line of code.                                                            
           The problem - plot can't be used in functions for further calculus, that's why I am looking for Array series shifting

Comment: //@version=5
**indicator('CloseOffset', overlay=true)
Shift = input.int(-100,"Shift")

plot(close, 'HistClose', color.new(color.blue, 0), 4, offset = Shift) **

Comment: [link] https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kyEyC9Rmb7grr69AzcOeGCzMDNow2n-s/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101488649560849801546&rtpof=true&sd=true